# jade get object keyname in iteration

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

```
var data = {
  thing: 'value1',
  thing2: 'value2',
  thing3: 'value3'
};

each val, index in data
    li= val.keyname??
```

The output I want is:

```
<li>thing</li>
<li>thing2</li>
<li>thing3</li>
```

Is this possible?

I tried just using 'index', but it iterated on the entire list of properties and prototype functions attached to the object, e.g. `$__, isNew, errors, _doc, $__original_save, save, _pres, _posts, toObject, toJSON, $__isNested` etc..

The `data` is from part of a `find` query from MongoDB.

In my usecase I do not know the names of the keys beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data must be a simple key-value object.

If You have most complicated object (like model or collection) use a `toJSON` pattern like in `Backbone.Model` or `Backbone.Collection`.

If You have a simple object, use `each val, idx` like this:

```
ul
  each val, idx in data
    li= idx
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/tomi77/5rb5hspk/2/

Comment: so close, but this does the same thing as index, iterates through all the prototype properties as well; as listed in the OP.

Comment: fine, here: `{ albany: 'a3', penrose: 'a3', christchurch: 'a4' }`, the problem is that there are a bunch of prototype values attached to that object in the data after its passed into jade, and that iteration is going through all of them too.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Use `toJSON` pattern like in `Backbone.Model` and `Backbone.Collection`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tomi77/5rb5hspk/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use library UnderscoreJS's invert method. Underscorejs.org

Comment: almost.. but that assumes the values will be unique, and they definitely are not (in my use case). Though it would work in the example I gave.